# Generate a floppy image on Windows

Tags: operating-system, cmd, bootloader, floppy

So, I have compiled an ASM boot program like this :

```
nasm -f bin -o bootsect bootsect.asm
```

And now I need to run the next UNIX command to generate a floppy image from the output, but i'm using MS Windows...

```
cat bootsect /dev/zero | dd of=floppyA bs=512 count=2880
```

Does someone know how can I do the equivalent in the Windows' cmd ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a port of Unix `dd` to the Win32 environment. Or you could use `rawwrite`. Both are available for download at http://www.chrysocome.net.